# Ionic 3 error: resource xml/network_security_config not found

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

When I try to run ‘ionic cordova build android’ I’m given this exception:

> Anroid resource linking failed
>   J:\workspaces\APCO\App\apco\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:22:
>   AAPT: error: dresource xml/network_security_config (aka
>   io.ionic.starter:xml/network_security_config) not found.

Problem is, I have network_security_config.xml inside ‘…APP-FOLDER\platforms\android\res\xml’ and ‘…APP-FOLDER\resources\android\xml’.

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
<application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:supportsRtl="true" >
...
```

My config.xml:

```
 <platform name="android">
 <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
 </edit-config>
 <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
```

Comment: Did you try to remove and add the Android platform?

Comment: @yazantahhan Yes! It worked. Actualy the problem wasn't necessaraly that, I found out after remove and add the Android Platform that building in android 7.0.0 was giving the problem, so I only had to build with 'ionic cordova build android@6.4.0'

Answer (score 2):

**in config.xml** 
replace

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
    </edit-config>
```

with

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
    </edit-config>
```

and add

```
<resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
```

**create** new file **network_security_config.xml** in resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <!-- note this is without http -->
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: I had to change the resource to: ```<resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />``` (res on app root level).